# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator in jquery/json

Tags: php, jquery, json

I create a json in php like this:

```
$details= array();
$ret = array();

for($i=0;$i<3;$i++) { $details["name"] = "name".$i;  $ret[] = $details;}
```

And then return it to a jquery ajax:

```
echo json_encode($ret,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
die();
```

In jQuery ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "index2.php?id=upload",
    type: "POST",
    data:  new FormData($("#form")[0]),
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,
    processData:false,
    returnType:"json",
    success: function(data)
    {
        console.log('names:'+JSON.stringify(data));
        $.each(data, function(i) 
        { 
            console.log('name:'+data[i]['name']);
         }
    },
```

first console log prints,but second:
I get this error:

> jquery-2.2.3.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to
>   search for 'length' in
>   [{"name":"name1"},{"name":"name2"},{"name":"name3"}]

Also I try

```
$.each(JSON.parse(data), function(i) 
                { ..}
```

but I  print empty:

> name:undefined

Comment: what about `data[i].name` ?

Comment: `var newData = JSON.stringify(data);
                $.each(newData, function(i) 
                { 
                    console.log('name:'+newData[i]['name']); // or check once newData[i].name
                }`

Comment: Show the JSON that actually goes to the browser, not the PHP code generating it. Also, your code as quoted won't run at all (syntax error, not just at the end). Instead of *retyping* code you're asking about, *copy-and-paste* it to avoid introducing irrelevancies.

Comment: Show us the result of `console.log('names:'+JSON.stringify(data));` Use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36742186/edit) link to amend your question. **Dont put it in a comment**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the javascript converts your json string into a javascript data type it will be an array of objects like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => name0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => name1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => name2
        )

)
```

So your javascript should be

Also `returnType:"json"` should be `dateType:"json"` as far as I know there is not such parameter as `returnType:`

```
   $.ajax({
        url: "index2.php?id=upload",
        type: "POST",
        data:  new FormData($("#form")[0]),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        dateType:"json",
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log('names:'+JSON.stringify(data));
            $.each(data, function(i,v) 
            { 
                console.log('name:'+v.name);
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   $.ajax({
        url: "index2.php?id=upload",
        type: "POST",
        data:  new FormData($("#form")[0]),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        returnType:"json",
        success: function(data)
        {
            console.log('names:'+JSON.stringify(data));
            $.each(JSON.parse(data), function(i) 
            { 
                console.log('name:'+i['name']);
            }
        },
```